# WPF DataBinding - Changing ComboBox's SelectedItem not calling ViewModel

Tags: wpf, data-binding

The following code is not calling the SelectedItem's property setter in my view model.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbGuaranteeType"  Margin="5,5,5,5" MinWidth="80" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource guaranteeTypesKey}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfToolkit:DataGridRow}}, Path=DataContext.GuaranteeType, Mode=TwoWay}"
      />
```

The view is a UserControl bound to a ViewModel.  The UserControl has a WpfToolkit datagrid which is bound to an ObservableCollection on the ViewModel.  The ObservableCollection consists of a `List<T>` items.  The above combobox is binding to the "GuaranteeType" property on one of the T items as follows:

```
public GuaranteeType? GuaranteeType
{
    get { return _guaranteeType; }
    set { _guaranteeType = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(ConstGuaranteeType); }
}
```

When the UserControl is loaded, the GuaranteeType property's getter is called and the SelectedItem is set correctly.  However, when I click on the ComboBox and attempted to change the SelectedItem, the setter for the GuarenteeType property is never called.

Additionally, I implemented the `SelectionChanged="cmbGuaranteeType_SelectionChanged"` in XAML against the View's codebehind and when the view is loading the SelectionChanged method is called once but it is not called when I release the mouse when trying to change the selected item of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for such a vague answer, but I've seen this happen before and I seem to remember it having to do with the click event of the grid unbinding the SelectedItem. Similar things happen when binding radio buttons.

For combo boxes I essentially always default to using a ListCollectionView to expose the underlying observable collection and set the XAML like so:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListCollectionViewPropertyHere}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Then from code you can grab the `ListCollectionViewPropertyHere.CurrentItem` if you are polling or subscribe to the `ListCollectionViewPropertyHere.CurrentItemChanged` event if you need to be notified on click.

Comment: What do you mean by polling in this context?   I did attempt a few things though; I changed the ItemsSource to point to a ListCollectionView on the ViewModel to no avail.  In the ViewModel I even subscribed to the CurrentChanging & CurrentChanged events but they only fired during the load and not on change.  The surprising thing is that eventhough the GuaranteeType property getter is returning the correct SelectedItem during the binding process, the ComboBox isn't showing a SelectedItem (like it was previously).